# How do you get to the root directory that I need to delete a file in?

Tags: directory, root

I need to get into the root directory to delete a file. How do I get there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will get you to the root from command line:

```
cd /
```

If you are using ftp it might go to the root of your ftp (not per definition the root of your system).

I would be careful if I was you: in general nobody creates files in "/".  Removing needs to be done with `sudo` in front of the `rm` and you need to be using an admin account.

Answer (score 1):

From a cli/terminal you can use the `sudo` command to assume root privileges, which you need to delete stuff from your root directory. If you're unfamiliar with cli commands you issue the command `gksudo nautilus` to open the file browser with root privileges. Do be carefull when deleting stuff in the root directory or you might break your system.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the graphic desktop

- click on the icon top left to open a "search" bar. Type "term" -
  short for terminal.
- Once the terminal window opens enter `cd /` (as
  mentioned above)

To delete files I would suggest using

```
rm -i /yourfilename /your/file/name
```

so that you can preview what is getting deleted - especially when using a wildcard (`*` and/or `?`)